# Debian - USB mouse not recognized by X?

Tags: debian, usb, kde, mouse

I can't seem to figure out how to properly configure my USB mouse: when I plug it, it simply gives no response, while the touchpad continues to work instead.

System informations:

- Lenovo Z50-70 Notebook
- 4.9.0-8-amd64, Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- KDE as Desktop Environment

The device I'm trying to use is detected as shown below:

```
    $ dmesg 
    [ 1302.008252] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
    [ 1302.149880] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=062a, idProduct=4102
    [ 1302.149884] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    [ 1302.149887] usb 2-1: Product: 2.4G Wireless Mouse
    [ 1302.149889] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: MOSART Semi.
    [ 1302.152124] input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/0003:062A:4102.0002/input/input17
    [ 1302.152602] hid-generic 0003:062A:4102.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
    [ 1302.165818] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 7
    [ 1305.600565] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
    [ 1305.742090] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=062a, idProduct=4102
    [ 1305.742094] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    [ 1305.742096] usb 2-1: Product: 2.4G Wireless Mouse
    [ 1305.742098] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: MOSART Semi.
    [ 1305.744261] input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/0003:062A:4102.0003/input/input18
    [ 1305.744524] hid-generic 0003:062A:4102.0003: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
```

But it is disconnected and reconnected every time I try to give input through it.

I can also trivially catch its raw input using `cat` command, but (I think) the real problem is that `xinput` does not list the said device:

```
salvo@Turuzzu:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Does anyone have some good hints?

PS: I tested two different mice, a wireless one and a wired one; both with the same results.